# CSS overlapping divs revealed with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html, overlapping

I attempting to create an 800x500 div with four overlapping divs inside the container that are 800x500.  On the initial load I'm trying to have 1/4 of each overlapping div display and eventually when you click or maybe mouse over one of the quadrants jquery will expand that quadrant from 400x250 to 800x500 and adjust the z index accordingly so the expanded div is on top.  I'm stumped at the beginning though.  I set up an 800x500 container div.  Inside that container I  placed 4 400x250 divs.  I was expecting that placing an 800x500 image in a 400x250 container would crop the image and I would see all four at the get go and then I was going to work on the transform.

Any help would be great.  Here is the [fiddle I've been playing with](http://jsfiddle.net/qz8rK/1/).

Or you can look at the code here for all you mental compilers.

```
<html>
<head>
      <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){    

    $("div").click(function () {
        $(this).effect("scale", { percent: 300, direction: 'both' }, 1000);
  });

    });
    </script>    
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

        <div class="top-left">
                <image src="http://kpbs.media.clients.ellingtoncms.com/img/photos/2010/11/12/nature-wolverines-snow_tx700.jpg?8e0a8887e886a6ff6e13ee030987b3616fc57cd3">
        </div>    
        <div class="top-right">
                <image src="http://www.adywallpapers.com/nature/260_nature_wallpapers.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-right">
                <image src="images/http://www.adywallpapers.com/nature/101_nature_wallpapers.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-left">
                <image src="http://www.adywallpapers.com/nature/192_nature_wallpapers.jpg">
        </div>         

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color:#000;
    }

#container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;            
}

.bottom-right {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color:yellow;
    z-index:-1;
    width: 400px;
    height:  250px;
}


.top-right{
    top:0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color:white;
    z-index:-2;
    width: 400px;
    height:  250px;
}

.bottom-left {
    position:absolute;  
    top:0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color:blue;
    z-index:-3;
    width: 400px;
    height:  250px;
}

.top-left{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background-color:black;
    z-index:-4;
    width: 400px;
    height:  250px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qz8rK/2/

I changed your css like this:

```
body {
background-color:#000;
}

.container {
position: absolute;
width: 800px;
height: 600px;            
}

.container div {
width: 400px;
height: 250px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.bottom-right {
position:absolute;
top:250px;
left: 400px;
background-color:yellow;
z-index:-1;
}


.top-right{
top:0px;
left: 400px;
background-color:white;
z-index:-2;
}

.bottom-left {
position:absolute;  
top:250px;
left: 0px;
background-color:blue;
z-index:-3;
}

.top-left{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
background-color:black;
z-index:-4;
}
```

Comment: Ka-Ching!  Thank you Sarah.  Now on to animating the divs so the reveal properly.

Comment: It's strange, in when I run the code in firefox outside of the fiddle the top-right div is on top of the top-left and not in the top right.

Comment: Did you check the absolute positions? The top-right div should have left: 400px;

Comment: nevermind, I didn't have the top-right div set to absolute.  Can jquery override absolute css?